# Germany: Freelance visa and traveling in Schengen

Tags: visas, schengen, freelance

I found this very comprehensive guide about freelance visa in Germany:
https://allaboutberlin.com/guides/how-to-get-a-german-freelance-visa

Does anyone of you know if I can travel Schengen with that visa or is it only a national visa? If I can travel with that visa in Schengen, are there any requirements to not leave Germany more than x days?

I know within Europe there are no border controls so any time abroad would be hard to track in most cases anyway.

Answer (score 4):

A D visa (and by extension a residence pemit), allows you to visit other Schengen states for 90 days in a 180 days period. The stays in the issuing countries doesn't count